# Microphone not changing after setting new constraints

Tags: javascript, electron

We are building an application in Electron and the microphone is not changing after setting a new deviceId. There is no error being shown.

```
//myId is an id retrieved from navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
const constraints = {audio: {deviceId: {exact: myId}}};
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
```

What are we doing wrong? When we test it on an external website, it looks like it is working correctly.

All our search results in nothing useful or on searches that are very outdated. Electron is a chromium browser. We have been stuck on this problem for more than a week. It doesn't work on Ubuntu and Windows 11 (only OS we have tested so far). We have not yet bothered with MacOs.

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure myId is not null, because when you first call `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()` it can return empty strings.
2. for me `const constraints = {audio: {deviceId: {exact: myId}}};` return error because of `exact`. For me worked `const constraints = {audio: {deviceId:  myId}};`
3. You missing one '}' at the end of `const constraints = {audio: {deviceId: {exact: myId}};`
4. If you set new devices you have to get new tracks from new stream and add to old stream.

It's working code that change microphone depending on which button you click.

script.js

```
let mediaStream;
let mic1Id, mic2Id;
navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then((res) => {
    mic1Id = res[2].deviceId;
    mic2Id = res[3].deviceId;
    const constraints = {
        audio: {
            deviceId: { exact: mic1Id },
        },
    };
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then((stream) => {
        mediaStream = stream;

        var audio = document.querySelector("audio");
        stream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = true;

        audio.srcObject = stream;
    });
});

function getAudioTrack(deviceId) {
    const constraints = {
        audio: {
            deviceId: {
                exact: deviceId,
            },
        },
    };
    return navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then((stream) => {
        return stream.getAudioTracks();
    });
}

function replaceAudioTrack(stream, newAudioTrack) {
    let audioTrack = stream.getAudioTracks()[0];
    stream.removeTrack(audioTrack);
    stream.addTrack(newAudioTrack);
}

let btn1 = document.querySelector("button:nth-of-type(1)");
let btn2 = document.querySelector("button:nth-of-type(2)");

btn1.onclick = () => {
    getAudioTrack(mic1Id).then((res) => replaceAudioTrack(mediaStream, res[0]));
};
btn2.onclick = () => {
    getAudioTrack(mic2Id).then((res) => replaceAudioTrack(mediaStream, res[0]));
};
```

index.html

```
    <audio autoplay></audio>
    <button>Mic 1</button>
    <button>Mic 2</button>
```

Comment: 1. the value is not an empty string.
2. Not using exact doesn't use the new microphone also. 
3. Sorry, that was just a syntax fault in the SO post. That has been corrected.
4. Can you elaborate? When we change the microphone, we have no audio that is currently playing.

Comment: @Wojtek322 check update. Then you just use method addTrack(). Maybe your mic have also set muted = true or enabled = false.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But this changes only for Audio objects and not on an application-wide level including external libraries that we are using. I can't seem to find anything related to changing the whole application (Electron app) which should solve my use case.